# How do I send updating data to a child component. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

If I have an object key values that we assume change due to some input. How do I update the child component that takes those values and displays them. When I send the values as props to the child component they obviously don't update and stay as the initial value set in tempData. So how would I prompt the child props to resend or update?

I already have functions that fetch the data and put it all into its places in the tempData object. Am I going about this wrong by setting the data in an Object?

```js
const Parent = () => {

const tempData = {
  location: "",
  weather: "",
  temperature: "",
};

return (
    <>
      <System onChange={(value) => urlHandler(value)} />
      <City onChange={(value) => setCity(value)} />
      <Data
        location={tempData.location}
        weather={tempData.location}
        temperature={tempData.temperature}
      />

</>
};

const Child = (props) => {

return(
<>
<div>location: {props.location}</div>
<div>temperature: {props.temperature}</div>
</>
)

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React has no way to detect that you have mutated `tempData` so it won't re-render the element with the new data.

Store the data in the **state** instead. Using the state API to update the state will trigger a re-render.

This is covered in the [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component) but that focuses on old-style class components. Modern code would use the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) in a function component  instead. This is also covered by the [MDN React tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_interactivity_events_state).